# Transaction Log usage fluctuation

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

The Transaction Log Usage fluctuating quite frequently.

When I run `DBCC SQLPERF('LOGSPACE')` it shows `Log Space Used (%)` as `3%` which is like `650MB` while at very next minute or two when I run it again it might show as 0.0123% without doing any kind of Log backup or anything and it happened few times.

Just wondering what it could be? I was trying to analyse Log usage pattern over the period of time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the recovery model on your database?

Comment: its Full recovery model

Comment: Are there any noteworthy messages in the sql error log around that time?

Comment: Do you happen to have any kind of mirroring or replication involved in this scenario?

Comment: no, I could not see any noteworthy message apart from quite few 'Login failed for user' messages. This database is part of High availability group though.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what the log_reuse_wait_description on sys.databases is when the log is big and then when the log is reduced

Comment: At now when log usage is reduced, the log_reuse_wait_desc is 'LOG-BACKUP' but now I have to wait when log is big because it is not fluctuating now.

Answer (score 1):

The information in your question leads me to believe that some kind of log truncation is occurring between your first invocation of `DBCC SQLPERF('LOGSPACE')` and your second invocation.  According to [The Transaction Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server#FactorsThatDelayTruncation), (specifically the section **Factors that can delay log truncation**),  there are numerous things that can prevent log truncation.  You mentioned the fact that the database is in a High Availability Group.  I'd suggest periodically querying the sys.databases catalog view (log_reuse_wait and log_reuse_wait_desc columns).  Perhaps "*a secondary replica of an availability group is applying transaction log records of this database to a corresponding secondary database.* and when that completes, the VLF's are marked for reuse."